# PHP Do something(process $_SESSION) when session ends

Tags: php, session

I want to gather user logs in a session and save it in the DB when the session is about to be deleted.
I couldn't find an answer which does not involve storing a Session ID in the DB and timers.

But... session is a server side feature, right?
The Server decides which session has ended and the server deletes it.

Is there really no way to call user script to process $_SESSION right before it gets deleted?

Comment: Considering the session ends either when the user logs out(that's easy enough to know) or when the user literally closes the browser(that's literally impossible to know), I don't think there is.

Comment: You would need to write your own session handler for this. http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php

Comment: I dont need to know why session has ended. I need to know when server secides to clear session data.

Comment: you could write the logs in database for every pageload. this way, you don't loose anyhing. if the user is logged out or the session expires, that specific log will not be logged anymore.

Comment: correct so you write your own session handler class that implements the `gc` function http://php.net/manual/en/sessionhandler.gc.php, the first link i provided has an example with read and write ... so it should be a good starting place for modifying it to use the `gc`, you will also want to use the `destroy` function for when you manually destroy a session.

Comment: machineaddict, additional calling DB each time when user is doing something? No way. Thx

Comment: cmorrissey, thank you. I'll try it.